# passing object between fragments buy using serializable cause error on pressing home button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 `Fragments` the first one contains 4 buttons. When a button is pressed the second `fragment` is loaded. the second fragment has an edit text. When the text is changed in the second `fragment` I want the the text in the first button to change .

[image: first Fragment] [image: Secrond fragment]

To achive this I made the first fragment as serilizable and passed object of the first fragment to the second fragment as serilizable. by using this object I chaged the text in the first fragment.

now the problem is when the home button is pressed when the second fragment is loaded a the app crashes with exception parcelable encountered ioexception writing serializable. now what should I do??

Comment: you must have a shared preference or a manager singleton for your shared data between both fragment, passing a fragment instance to another is not the best way.

Comment: the shared preference can store a value. but i want the first fragemt to change the text on its button when i return to that fragment. how is it possible without the use of an object of the class??

Comment: Who would have guessed that Steve Jobs and Bill Gates were actually Android developers?!

Answer (score 0):

User chared preference to stock the value of the Text, 
From the Fragment onResume(),method, update your TextView.